# Insert mysql data from remote mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Using php, I am trying to access a remote mysql table and import it into a local server. However, I cannot figure out how to get the importing working. I keep getting "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" error.

```
<?php
$localDB = new mysqli("", "", "", "");  //filled in for actual but ignored for question
$remoteDB = new mysqli("", "", "", ""); //filled in for actual but ignored for question
$pat = "0";

$getQuery = "SELECT eventname, da, mont, yea, autoinc, pic, codez, emai, pricof, excl FROM `eventannoun` WHERE da > ?";
$getStmt = $remoteDB->prepare($getQuery);
$getStmt->bind_param('i', $pat); //error here
$getStmt->execute();
$getStmt->bind_result($message, $da, $mont, $yea, $autoinc, $pic, $codez, $emai, $pricof, $excl);

$putQuery = "INSERT INTO `eventannoun` (eventname, da, mont, yea, autoinc, pic, codez, emai, pricof, excl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$putStmt = $localDB->prepare($putQuery);
$putStmt->bind_param('siiiiisssi',$message, $da, $mont, $yea, $autoinc, $pic, $codez, $emai, $pricof, $excl);

while ($getStmt->fetch()) {
  $putStmt->execute();
  $putStmt->fetch();
}
$getStmt->close();
$putStmt->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I keep getting "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object" error.

[**mysqli::prepare**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) returns `false` if there was an error.

`false` is not an object, thus you get the error:

`call to method function on bind_param() on a non-object`.

You can get the error message by examining the [**mysqli::error**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) property. An excerpt from the documentation reads as follows.

> Returns the last error message for the most recent MySQLi function call that can succeed or fail.

```
// at the top of your script place this.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

/* Do all your connection stuff */

$getQuery = ""; // query goes here
// your problem is actually on this line
$getStmt = $remoteDB->prepare($getQuery); 
if (!$stmt) {
    $err = $remoteDB->error; 
    echo $err; // this will tell you why your query is invalid
    // do something with $err
}
```

The most typical reason why `prepare` fails is a malformed or invalid query, but without knowing the customer schema or constraints I can't be sure what your particular problem is.

Another potential problem is that you are failing to connection to the remote database. But i doubt that is the problem as you would have seen the warning messages. Here is some code to help with that possibility.

```
$remoteDB = new mysqli("","","","");
if (mysqli_connect_errno() !== 0) {
    print_r( mysqli_connect_error() );
    die;    
}
```

Comment: It was not returning an error message at localDB or remoteDB

Comment: @user1667601 What do you mean by "it"?

Comment: the php script did not return any specific error other than the one mentioned in the question

Comment: @user1667601 the `$remoteDB->error` one or the `mysqli_connect_error()` one?

Comment: Place `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);` before you start calling `new mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can remote connect to that mysql?

Check if the 3306 port is open on the server (with tools like http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ )

If it's open, you may have to whitelist your ip

Comment: This is probably not the issue as you get a warning msg like `PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli()` when mysqli can't connect. Also `prepare` will thorw a warning if there is no database connection.

Comment: That is unfortunately not the issue. I am able to connect remotely.